# Effect of more number of functions in an application

Tags: oop, functional-programming

If I have a large number of functions in my application, Do they effect the execution speed of the application?

For example: I have 10000 functions in my application but each time that I run my application only 1 or 2 functions will work. It is not known beforehand which function(s) will be called, it depends on user given input.

Does it changes the execution speed it I have many number of functions?

Answer (score 0):

The speed shouldn't be significantly affected in your case. The number of procedures defined is much less important than the [computational complexity](http://jeremykun.com/2011/06/14/big-o-notation-a-primer/) of each procedure called.

Think about it. A 2.5GHz processor can theoretically perform more than 10 billion floating point operations per second (FLOPS). The time required to load a fixed number of procedures into memory, even a million lines of code, will remain constant and fairly trivial, but if one of your procedures is complex enough, the number of operations can increase massively over a comparatively few iterations.

Comment: And code that is not used may ever be loaded into memory at all.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

9,998 functions not used, but still in since they are referenced, does not affect performance unless you need to parse all code at each run.

I'm thinking the case analysis size might affect the performance. If you have 10,000 fucntions and only use about 2 each time, then you'll have about 5,000 outcomes and that means a lot of tests if it's a linear analysis or about 13 if it's binary.

I'd start with profiling the code to find the bottlenecks.